# Understanding Cylinders expressed as Inequalities

Tags: geometry, inequality

I am currently studying for the MEXT exam (an underdrag math exam for people seeking to studying in Japan with a MEXT Scholarship) and meanwhile I understand most questions I do not know how to approach this one at all. Can someone give me some tips or advice on how to approach this question or what to study in order to answer it? I do not need the answer as I was given the answer in a seprate document, yet I want to learn how to solve it. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: To get you started: what are the boundary surfaces of $C$?

Comment: @amd what I don't understand is what is meant by "let C be the part of the cylinder that satisfies 0 <= z <= y". Since I have never done a problem like this I do not understand this. What does "z" represent?

Comment: You’re working in three dimensions. $z$ is just the usual coordinate, just like $x$ and $y$. If this were a two-dimensional problem, the inequality $x^2+y^2\le r^2$ would describe a disc, not a cylinder.